# Merging 2 applications together (ASP.NET MVC - JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, asp.net

So I have an application that deals with some basic membership functionality (Login, Register, User Profiles) and I also have another application that is a basic HTML page that uses JavaScript to generate questions from a database and then say if the input is correct.

What I want to do is merge the 2 applications together. One application is written in ASP.NET MVC C# using an SQL Server Database. The other application is written in Javascript, HTML and a SQLITE database.

How do I go about merging the 2 applications together?

I am using Visual Studio 2019, with an ASP.NET Web Application

I have already tried to add the Javascript scripts to my Scripts folder and outside the scripts folder in the ASP.NET solution, added the HTML page to the solution and the database file.

Do I need a plugin for reading SQLITE databases?

What happens is that I can access the HTML page but no JavaScript will run, however I am not sure this is because of my implementation of the application or if it cannot read the SQLITE database to generate the questions.

I don't think I need to add any code, as both applications work fine seperately and I assume there isn't much configuration as they have no dependencies with each other. I just want to have a button on the HTML page of one application take me to a page on the other application in the same solution whilst both applications function correctly.

JavaScript Application Includes;

- Database.SQLITE
- Index.html
- question.js
- answer.js
- main.js

MVC Application includes;

- Data Class Library
- Service Class Library
- Web Application Library

  - SQL Server Database

Answer (score 0):

hi if you add html project to asp.net project  you should be sure that html project content like javascripts files are in wwwroot folder and your middlewares for routing and static files are added to startup file then be sure that js files addresses in html files are set correctly

Comment: I just added all the files into a project, so no extra addresses need to be modfied. I also created a folder that housed all the application files and this still didnt work.